# What directory upload to server - PROJECT SYMFONY

Tags: symfony, configuration, configuration-files, filezilla

I would like know what directory have that upload to the server through FTP, my project currently is done with symfony3.3.
My doubt is, should upload cache directory and which directorys takes like config symfony when the project is in production ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in **shared hosting** you need to upload all your files (except the caches and logs : "var/cache" and "var/logs"):

Put your the files in your root folder except the "web" folder put its content on your public folder generally "public_html"

Answer (score 1):

You should upload all your file expect `vendors` and you should install composer via ssh and it will reload the vendor directory and files automatically via your kernel and autoload  . Below a link that could help :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

Comment: Check the version of PHP PHP -v i just deploy  a symfony project yesterday i can  help you  if you  have problems  tomorow